# How do I log every command executed by a user?

Tags: linux, user-management

I want to monitor all user's activity in my server.

Even when the user executes a shell command from some editor like vim I want to
see them in the log file.

I have checked the tool acct but it is not listing the complete commands.
(Please correct me if I have missed some options which does already).

Which Linux tool I should be looking at to solve this problem?

Comment: .  man script(1)

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/323270/how-can-i-make-bash-to-log-shell-commands-to-syslog and http://serverfault.com/questions/242842/how-to-log-commands-logins-in-linux

Comment: A nice reference https://8gwifi.org/docs/linux-monitor-commands.jsp

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add this line to your pam config responsible for logins (its system-auth on redhat based distros)

```
session    required     pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

To find out what was done, you can use.

```
ausearch -ts <some_timestamp> -m tty -i
```

This produces an output like this:

```
 type=TTY msg=audit(11/30/2011 15:38:39.178:12763684) : tty pid=32377 uid=root
 auid=matthew major=136 minor=2 comm=bash data=<up>,<ret>
```

The only downside to this is is can be a little bit difficult to read, but it is much better than most proposed solutions since in theory it could be used to record an entire session, warts n all.

Edit: Oh and you can use aureport to generate a list that can be more helpful.

```
# aureport --tty
...
12. 11/30/2011 15:50:54 12764042 501 ? 4294967295 bash "d",<^D>
13. 11/30/2011 15:52:30 12764112 501 ? 4294967295 bash "aureport --ty",<ret>
14. 11/30/2011 15:52:31 12764114 501 ? 4294967295 bash <up>,<left>,<left>,"t",<ret>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS When I check the folder /lib/security/ the module is not present but there is a man page present for that module. I think I have hit this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/588547 Is there any other way I can install that module ?

Comment: The bug report suggests a fix and update was distributed.

Comment: @Mlfe I compiled the PAM source code and copied the .so file in /lib/security/ and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `pam_tty_audit.so` will capture all interactions, *including passwords*

Comment: @CameronKerr : the password issue is fixed : https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2013-May/msg00007.html

Comment: Note, it's worth mentioning that for the above to work the `auditd` daemon needs to be enabled first (it wasn't by default on my CentOS 6.7 install).  To start the daemon, use: `service auditd start`, and to make this change persistent (after reboots), use `chkconfig auditd on`   Source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_PAM_for_Auditing.html and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-starting_the_audit_service.html

Comment: I was going to ask 'why do we need this', but by default, the kernel does not audit input on any TTY.  https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tty_audit

Comment: `tty is an unsupported option`

Comment: @L29Ah no its not, on CentOS 6 it is there. Not sure what distro you're rolling out for that not to be a supported option.

Answer (score 9):

The best solution to your problem would be Linux' built-in [audit](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) system. Use `man 8 auditd` or check this page for more information: http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd.

Also, you can check [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) - while it is slightly out of the scope of your question, it shows how the audit system works.

Answer (score 4):

A lesser known trick, but easily the most awesome is just to use the built-in audit capabilities of `sudo`. Sudo ships with a `sudoreplay` command that makes replaying sessions easy. It will even relay `vim` sessions (as you suggest).

Here's how to use it in a few easy steps:

1. Install [`sudosh`](https://github.com/cloudposse/sudosh/releases) on your system; this is a shell wrapper around the `sudo` command that makes a user `sudo` themselves (not `root`) and can be used as a system login shell
2. Enable `sudo` logging. Edit `/etc/sudoers.d/sudosh`:

   `Defaults log_output
   Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
   Defaults!/sbin/reboot !log_output`
3. Add this command to `/etc/shells` to permit logins using it:

   `/usr/bin/sudosh`

   **Tip**: to prevent users from using other shells to login, remove those other shells from `/etc/shells`.
4. Update the user `foobar` to use the `sudosh` shell.

   `chsh -s /usr/bin/sudosh foobar`

For more detailed information, see: https://github.com/cloudposse/sudosh/

Comment: how sudosh can be installed? I can't find any instruction about that

Comment: @medBouzid Now there are releases: https://github.com/cloudposse/sudosh/releases/tag/0.3.0

Answer (score 3):

You could use [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy).

It is a simple command logging library, and not a proper audit solution (easily circumvented).
Disclosure: I am current snoopy maintainer.

Comment: Can you provide a smart way to set the environment so that it cannot get circumvented?

Comment: @GeorgeY, no. If you need an actual accounting solution (non-circumventable), use an appropriate tool for that, like auditd-based mechanism mentioned above (or anything else that is kernel-based, which Snoopy isn't).

Answer (score 0):

here's a magic solution : 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html

- yum install psacct (redhat)
- sudo apt-get install acct

you ca display statistic about user commands/connection etc..

List all commands invoked by a given user ...

Search the accounting logs by command name:
$ lastcomm rm
$ lastcomm passwd

and so on, for more informations please visit the above link ..

Comment: In the question was said: 'acct it is not listing the complete commands'.

Comment: "magic solution" is usually a bad thing, especially for security: I don’t want to install things if I don’t understand how they work.