# Audit of who ran what command via ssh with shared account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, user-management

We use shared accounts on our servers. Each uses a different ssh key. Is there a way to create an audit trail of who ran what commands? We can distinguish real "users" by the ssh key used.

Comment: I don't think there is a way, and especially not one that isn't easily bypassed or an ugly hack.  It's much better to abolish shared accounts.

Comment: While we're still small, it's hugely convenient sharing accounts for things like pushing to prod. This isn't a trust issue, but rather being able to easily track down who's running long-running commands for example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to do it in one place, but if you're willing to trudge through the logs you can get SSHD to log the key fingerprint when someone logs in:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/can-i-find-out-which-ssh-key-was-used-to-access-an-account

And then log the commands:

[How do I log every command executed by a user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/336217/how-do-i-log-every-command-executed-by-a-user)

Notice in the comments there's a note about getting this to work on ubuntu.

You can then connect the session ID found in the system logs to the command logs through ausearch:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch

In the end, if you can separate the accounts (and manage permissions based on a group?) that might simplify things for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the commands logged are more like key presses, so if a user hits up+enter those keys are logged rather than the command.

Comment: That is because the software doing the logging is unaware of the shell.  If it operated any other way it could be defeated by running a subshell.